# Aligning issue using input-group/input-group-addon in Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my project I have a form with three inputs, and for all I want to use the `input-group` and `input-group-addon` offered by `Bootstrap`. If I use the following code,

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <span style="text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs Frank</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsFrank, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="input-group form-group">
    <span style="text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon"> ... vs any other guy</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsAnyOther, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="input-group form-group ">
    <span style="text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs any other monster</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsAnyMonster, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

the result looks like this,

[image]

Now, I'd like to have the labels of the last two rows lined up, but the one of the first row shorter. If I add some width to them, as follows,

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <span style="width:15ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs Frank</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsFrank, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="input-group form-group">
    <span style="width:25ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon"> ... vs any other guy</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsAnyOther, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="input-group form-group ">
    <span style="width:25ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs any other monster</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vsAnyMonster, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

Now the whole first control is shortened! How can I prevent that without giving all the controls explicit width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `min-width` for the input-group.

**CSS**

```css
 .input-group {
   min-width: 100%;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group form-group">
      <span style="width:15ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs Frank</span>
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group form-group">
      <span style="width:25ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs any other guy</span>
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group form-group">
      <span style="width:25ch; text-align:left;" class="input-group-addon">... vs any other monster</span>
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/yGBjmDY4Q9)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work as the width of the larger groups is dynamical (they fill a `col-md-4`), and if I set the `min-width` of less that that size it still looks as above, and if it is too big, everything goes wrong. So you are basically suggesting fixing the width explicitly, which I didn't want to do!